# Extend XHTML with namespaces

Tags: html, xml, xhtml, web-standards

I've seen this somewhere, but I don't remeber the page.

I'd like to extend the HTML tags, so then I can add my own attributes to the HTML elements, I saw a example where the developer added a new xmlns to the page definition, so he could add new things and still be a valid XHTML.

What is the name of this technique and where could I find information about it?

Cheers.

PS: Or maybe I've dreamed this? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an article on this [topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301515.aspx). However it would not be "valid" as XHTML is part of a international standard.

Comment: It's valid if it validates against the XHTML schema. That is what validity means in XML.

Comment: I am referring to the W3C validation.

Comment: W3C, World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) develop and maintain the standards that we all use for HTML and CSS. These standard defines how things should work, and with HTML and CSS how browsers (should) render the tags. While adding a namespace and your own tags may be structurally valid, it is not recognized as valid by the W3C and therefore browsers may have issues.

Comment: D'oh!! The website has to be W3C compilant, so I cannot use this then :(  Thanks very much!